# Anamorphic video with silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, video, video-streaming, video-processing

currently I'm trying to make a silverlight application for my application. The question on hand is that is it possible, and how, to display anamorphic video. the main purpose of this is to save bitrate per frame.

for example, anamorphic for 848x480 is -> 720x480, or anamorphic for 1080 is 1440x1080, which later resize to 1920x1080.

If my videos encode into anamorphic, and later on the player extend it to the correct size, it could save a lot of bandwidth on stream and lose "not much" of the quality or even remain the same quality. How should i do this in Silverlight or does it even support?

Im a newbie in silverlight so please help me out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the SL MediaElement natively supports anamorphic.  If it doesn't, you could set the MediaElement's Stretch property and size your MediaElement to the correct aspect ratio.  Here's more on the Stretch property:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.stretch(VS.95).aspx